# Inserting line break between visualized database entries when printed in index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a small app where a user can make entries into a text box, press enter and then the string they entered will be recorded in a section below the text box.

The things the person enters, called `Lessons` are displayed in the bottom of the page with the following code.

```
<% @allLessons.each do |lesson| %> 
    <tr>
        <td class="my-lessons">
            <b><%= lesson.content %></b> – <%= lesson.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %>
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
```

I'm trying to write something that looks at the date of each lesson and if that date is greater than the previous day's date, it inserts a line break between the outputted entries.

I'm very puzzled on how to do this. Would it be best to do all embedded Ruby in `home.html.erb` or use the `pages controller` to help out here as well?

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon the previous answer, something like `lesson.created_at.strftime("%Y%m%d").to_i > previous_lesson_date.strftime("%Y%m%d).to_i` would solve the abovementioned problem, assuming `lesson.created_at` and `previous_lesson_date` are both properly Time objects.

There may be a more direct solution taking better advantage of the Time object.

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
<% @allLessons.each do |lesson| %>
  <% previous_lesson_date = lesson.created_at %>
    <tr>
        <td class="my-lessons">
            <b><%= lesson.content %></b> – <%= lesson.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %>
            <% if lesson.created_at > previous_lesson_date %>
              <br />
            <% end %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Is the literal answer.  Since the current lesson will almost always have a greater date (since it will have been created a few seconds later).  I think you'll probably need to play with Rails date functions to get what you're really looking for.